# Fedora31 kernel is not loading after a recent upgrade

Tags: linux, fedora, uefi, linux-kernel

I just installed fedora31 on my Dell Inspiron 5567 and ran `dnf upgrade --refresh` which ran normally and updated all the packages including kernel core and kernel modules. But after I restarted the computer I get three options for loading kernel and non of them will load, I just get a blank screen and nothing else. So I edited the grub line to remove quite but then I get only one line `EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled.` when loading the kernel and then nothing else happens. I even tried to turn off the secure boot but that is also not working and I just get a blank screen.
What should I do now to restore the system?

Comment: if you edit the grub line and remove both `quiet` and `rhgb`, do you get any more boot messages?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No I only get "EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled" and nothing else

Comment: Does your machine still boot normally with a live CD/DVD/USB?

Comment: Yes it boots normally from live usb and I am even able to install from it but as soon as I run dnf update the problem reappears.

Comment: Wow, that's disappointing.  Does your laptop have a TPM?  If so, I wonder if disabling that in BIOS settings might allow it to boot.  Although, this shouldn't be necessary.  Also wondering, ... If you `dnf upgrade -x AllTheKernelPackages`, i.e., exclude every kernel package, does the upgrade complete normally and you are able to reboot norrmally?

Comment: Other BIOS changes I've read include `Bios -> Advanced -> Sleep Mode = "Force S3"`, but I don't know if that applies to your system, nor what other consequences there may be.

Comment: Also wondering if the machine is operating "normally", but without any screen updates.  Can you `ssh` in and look at `dmesg`, etc.?

Comment: @rickhg12hs actually disabling tpm worked. But I still don't get it if this is due to a bug?

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug to me. Is everything fully upgraded now? And, do you have the latest BIOS, drivers, etc., from Dell?

Comment: Would you contribute to a/some Redhat Bugzilla entries? https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1786481 https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1779611

Comment: Yeah everything is upgraded now.

Comment: I will definitely contribute

Comment: The solution discussed in Red Hat Bugzilla 1724262 may be of interest to people.